# How to return ResultSet in SQL Wrapper class

Tags: java, mysql

So I'm creating a simple MySQL wrapper class in Java just for my personal ease of use though I have a question.

In every example of MySQL in Java, the `ResultSet` is closed, followed by the `Statement`, then the `Connection`. Is the order of this important and if not, does the `ResultSet` have to be closed?

I want to return the ResultSet though if I can't do that, I have to find some other way to return the query's result.

Comment: Given the fact that you created them in order (`Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`), closing them out of order could actually prevent them from freeing resources they've otherwise created on the server.  By convention, they tend to be closed in the reverse order they are made.  Also, you might want to create a new `Statement` or `ResultSet`, so you don't want to be closing them out of order. You may also want to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which makes life SO much easier ;)

Comment: from java 7 onwards use try with resource and not need to worry about closing

Comment: How big is your data set? Are you trying to retrieve 10's of records? Maybe millions of records? It can make a huge difference to select an appropriate answer!

Comment: @JoD. At this time, probably no more than a couple hundred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is order important?

Yes in general it is a good practice to close resources in reverse order . Also in Java 7 try-with-resources, the order is reverse i.e. the resource opened last is closed first.

> Passing result set to other components?

You can use [`CachedRowSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) for that, it is a result set which is disconnected from datasource and is safe to pass to other components.

Quoting Oracle javadocs:

> A `CachedRowSet` object is a disconnected rowset, which means that it
>   makes use of a connection to its data source only briefly. It connects
>   to its data source while it is reading data to populate itself with
>   rows and again while it is propagating changes back to its underlying
>   data source. The rest of the time, a `CachedRowSet` object is
>   disconnected, including while its data is being modified. Being
>   disconnected makes a RowSet object much leaner and therefore much
>   easier to pass to another component. For example, a disconnected
>   `RowSet` object can be serialized and passed over the wire to a thin
>   client such as a personal digital assistant (PDA).

**EDIT:**

Based on comment of @JoD. You should consider the data size and the problem you are trying to solve before you choose any option.

> If you are handling a query, maybe as part of an ETL job, that needs
>   to handle 4 GB of memory, do you really want to have that 4GB
>   completely in memory before you start any further processing?
>   CachedRowSet is very good given certain situation, and is definitely
>   worth mentioning here. But we should consider this in the proper
>   context

Comment: If you are handling a query, maybe as part of an ETL job, that needs to handle 4 GB of memory, do you really want to have that 4GB completely in memory before you start any further processing? `CachedRowSet` is very good given certain situation, and is definitely worth mentioning here. But we should consider this in the proper context (which the OP did not sufficiently sketch).

Comment: @JoD. Good addition. I completely agree with you. But as OP did not furnish those details, I thought I should mention it. I would edit the post to include this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to `close` resources in the reverse of the order they are opened. The [`Statement.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) Javadoc says (in part)

> **Note**: When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object, if one exists, is also closed.

Instead of returning a `ResultSet`, it's common to implement a [`ValueObject`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object#Value_Objects_in_Java) and return a `Collection` of your `ValueObject` type. This is usually a Plain Old Java Object (or POJO), JavaBean or Data Transfer Object (DTO).

Comment: I sincerely disagree with the statement 'it's common to implement a ValueObject and return a Collection of your ValueObject type'. A `ResultSet` is a very good representation of your data without having to have the entire result actually in memory. It allows processing-while-you-traverse. It is very important when processing very big data sets. I think it is a good practice to handle a ResultSet, as long as you keep the connection in scope.